# Google Script to Copy cells value to another Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having 2 google sheet, having checkbox on 1st Sheet.
Requirement: When the checkbox is checked , Value from Cell C5 need to be stored in the Sheet2. When the checkbox is checked i.e value is 'True', the value in cell C5 of the Sheet1 needs to be submitted in the Sheet2 in the continuous manner.
I know this is the silly requirement, but I failed after several attempts as well.

Comment: pls, share a spreadsheet and your first attempts

Comment: Pls check this link, i have removed my earlier attempts which usually copies the entire row and pastes in sheet 2. I wanted only a specific cell to be copy pasted. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RiLjepEpYhkhCTgMHxrTxSI7GWloj954C4dsq0jT11E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var sh1 = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh1.getName() == 'Sheet1' && r.getA1Notation() == 'D5' && r.getValue() == true) {
    var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    sh2.getRange('A' + (sh2.getLastRow() + 1)).setValue(r.offset(0, -1).getValue())
    r.setValue(!r.getValue())
  }
}
```

Comment: C'est super, merci Mike. (Thanks,Mike)

Answer (score 0):

#### Store C5 in Sheet2 When Checkbox is checked

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh1 = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh1.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    var sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue());
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```